# How do I get Silverwood saplings?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

Silverwood trees apparently purify the area around them, and have their own aura nodes. It seems like a no-brainer to plant a couple of them around my base to offset the damage my inept thaumaturgical tinkering is doing.

However, I haven't been able to get any silverwood saplings at all. The Thaumonomicon has this to say:

> a silverwood sapling [is] a prize beyond measure.

So I assume it's not as easy as cutting down silverwood trees. Doing that yields nothing at all, aside from the wood.

Is there something special I have to do to get these saplings, or is it even possible at all? I know the saplings exist as items, but that could just be for server ops to spawn in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They come from the leaves of silverwood trees, the same as any other tree. They are, however, extremely rare, so maybe expect one from a whole tree.

This is to balance the fact that plating one makes an Aura node near (or inside) the tree.

Comment: Really? I cut down 4 of the things and got nothing at all. Is there maybe a preferred biome for them? Mystcraft ought to help with this.

Comment: @lunboks Probability can be like that...

Comment: Note that in Thaumcraft 3 they no longer create new nodes the same way—now the created node is empty and sucks up nearby nodes' aura, so they only move aura around now (and generate Flux in the process!).

Answer (score 1):

I've been told you can get one sapling out of maybe every three trees you cut down. Seems like it would be more efficient to just build your base around the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grafter to get like a 25% chance every leaf

Comment: Is there a source for your percentage chance?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do it is I use Force Mitts, which look like the bear claws. I've either gotten really lucky or that Force Mitts have a higher sapling spawn. I've gotten up to a dozen saplings off of one tree and I normally average 5-6.

Comment: What mod are these "Force Mitts" from? I've never heard about them. And that's quite the ridiculously high droprate. That's certainly balance breaking.

Comment: @Arperum they're from DartCraft - and they have a special bonus for silverwood saplings. It is not uncommon for DartCraft to be called balance breaking.